# Prevent delete on single row with trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Workspaces (
AreaNr CHAR(2)
    CONSTRAINT ck_a_areanr REFERENCES Areas(AreaNr)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
SpaceNr INT
    CONSTRAINT ck_spacenr CHECK (SpaceNr > 0 AND SpaceNr < 1001),
Area DECIMAL(2,1)
    CONSTRAINT ck_areal CHECK (area > 0),
CONSTRAINT ck_workspaces PRIMARY KEY (AreaNr, SpaceNr)
)
```

Now I want to create a trigger that prevents a delete on a single row (randomly chosen) from the table Workspaces. At the moment I have the following trigger, but this trigger still allows removal of single rows.

Current trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteWorkspace ON Workspaces
FOR DELETE AS

BEGIN
DECLARE @Count int
SET @Count = @@ROWCOUNT;

IF @Count >= (SELECT SUM(row_count)
FROM sys.dm_db_partition_stats
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('Workspaces') AND index_id = 1
)

BEGIN
RAISERROR('You cannot delete all rows from Workspaces!',16,1)
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
RETURN;
END

END
GO
```

Desired result: I want to be able to prevent a delete on a single row on the table above, and I would be very thankful if someone could help me to alter the trigger above so that this could be fixed. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to work with the deleted virtual table in this instance. I'm not entirely sure why you only care about *single* row deletes, but here is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER deleteWorkspace ON Workspaces
FOR DELETE AS

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) = 1
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Single Delete Not Allowed!', 16, 1)
ROLLBACK
END
ELSE
RAISERROR('Multiple Rows Being Deleted, Allowed!', 16, 1)
BEGIN
END

END
GO
```

-Sean

Comment: I had to use  the following format in exchange of RAISEERROR for some reason (SQL 2012) `THROW 51000, 'Delete not Allowed.', 1;`